# File Uploading in deployed Django applications

Tags: django, heroku, django-models

Where to store the images when a Django application is deployed through "Heroku" if I need to upload images using the same application after deployment ?

Amazon S3 services provide a solution but  the  file accessing urls has a certain expiry period, so after  maximum of 7days I cannot access the file using the same URL

Answer (score 1):

Heroku comes with a bunch of add-on that are very useful, one of which is called **Cloudinary** and the setup is pretty easy with Django : https://elements.heroku.com/addons/cloudinary

This situation is so common that Heroku provide a tutorial that you can follow to setup Cloudinary for your Django project : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cloudinary.

**Cloudinary** comes with a free plan so you don't have to worry about spending your money when testing out.

I have used it for many year, great add-on